# Custom font in UISegmentedControl disable adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have set a custom font for my UISegmentedControl, but it seems to disable the default *autoAdjustFontSizeToFitWidth* parameter.

Before:
[image: Font size is fit to width]
After:
[image: Font size is not fit to width anymore]

Here is the code I apply to set my custom font:

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)subview;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:DEFAULT_FONT size:DEFAULT_FONT_SIZE];
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[segmentedControl setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is there a way to preserve it? Many thanks.

**EDIT:** I would like to avoid

```
 segmentedControl.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = YES;
```

if possible to always have same width for every segment.

Comment: There's no such thing as autoAdjustFontSizeToFitWidth. Did you set the property correctly?

Comment: I mean autoAdjustFontSizeToFitWidth like UILabel property. I would like to find a property like this but for a segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to do this. You can search through the subviews of the segment control and set the properties.

```
+ (void) setAdjustsFontForWidth:(UIView *) view {
    NSArray * subvies = view.subviews;
    for(UIView * view in subvies) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel * label = (UILabel *)view;
            NSLog(@"label found: %@", label.text);
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;
            label.minimumScaleFactor = .1;
        } else {
            [self setAdjustsFontForWidth:view];
        }
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
[Utils setAdjustsFontForWidth:mySegmentControl];
```